# Best practice to add vue js based admin template into laravel app

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Found a vue js based admin dashboard https://github.com/PanJiaChen/vue-element-admin, and wanted to use it in my fresh laravel based app.

Because the structure of admin dashboard and laravel app differences, not sure, which is the best way to handle such kind of tasks.

Tried to put scss, js  files in laravel's resources directory, but faced not properly setted paths, scss load issues using laravel mix, for what any of suggested solutions didn't worked for me.

my package.json file looks like

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "0.18.0",
        "clipboard": "2.0.4",
        "codemirror": "5.45.0",
        "driver.js": "0.9.5",
        "dropzone": "5.5.1",
        "echarts": "4.2.1",
        "element-ui": "2.7.0",
        "file-saver": "2.0.1",
        "js-cookie": "2.2.0",
        "jsonlint": "1.6.3",
        "jszip": "3.2.1",
        "normalize.css": "7.0.0",
        "nprogress": "0.2.0",
        "path-to-regexp": "2.4.0",
        "screenfull": "4.2.0",
        "showdown": "1.9.0",
        "sortablejs": "1.8.4",
        "tui-editor": "1.3.3",
        "vue": "2.6.10",
        "vue-count-to": "1.0.13",
        "vue-router": "3.0.2",
        "vue-splitpane": "1.0.4",
        "vuedraggable": "2.20.0",
        "vuex": "3.1.0",
        "xlsx": "0.14.1",
        "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.9.6",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "fast-sass-loader": "^1.4.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/register": "7.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "3.5.3",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "3.5.1",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.7.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "3.5.3",
        "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
        "autoprefixer": "^9.5.1",
        "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
        "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "chalk": "2.4.2",
        "chokidar": "2.1.5",
        "connect": "3.6.6",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
        "eslint": "5.15.3",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "5.2.2",
        "fuse.js": "3.4.4",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
        "husky": "1.3.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "3.*",
        "lint-staged": "8.1.5",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "mockjs": "1.0.1-beta3",
        "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
        "plop": "2.3.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "runjs": "^4.3.2",
        "sass": "^1.15.3",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "2.1.3",
        "script-loader": "0.7.2",
        "serve-static": "^1.13.2",
        "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "svg-sprite-loader": "4.1.3",
        "svgo": "1.2.0",
        "vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
        "webpack": "^3.12.0",
        "webpack-assets-manifest": "^1.0.0",
        "webpack-build-notifier": "^0.1.28",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1",
        "webpack-clean-obsolete-chunks": "^0.4.0",
        "webpack-cleanup-plugin": "^0.5.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
        "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4"
    }
}
```

and my app.scss file

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

.navbar-laravel {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}
```

This particular error I was not able to resolved

> ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-5!./node_modules/style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src!./resources/sass/app.scss

Comment: Please can you show the code for your `resources/sass/app.scss` file and your `webpack.mix.js` file?

Comment: @RossWilson I've edited my answer and added content of `resources/sass/app.scss`